# Rounding error R

Tags: r

When I run this calculation: `2.36*7299.83` in R is returning `17227.599` but the correct answer should be `17227.5988`. Even when I run `options(digits=8)` before or `round(2.36*7299.83, 4)` it still gets the wrong answer.

It does not look like floating point error, because it is in the fourth decimal place.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: `17227.5988` is 9 digit long.

Comment: `it's returning 17227.599` => what is returning 17227.599?

Comment: Hum, that is not decimals digits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify the format:

```
formatC(2.36*7299.83, digits=4, format = "f")
```

> "17227.5988"

```
formatC(2.36*7299.83, digits=8, format = "f")
```

> "17227.59880000"

Answer (score 0):

the default `digits` is 7.

```
getOption("digits")
# [1] 7
print(round(2.36*7299.83, 4), digits=9)
# [1] 17227.5988
```